# Flutter initialization failed.couldn't find "libflutter.so"

Tags: android, flutter

E/FlutterLoader( 4087): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader( 4087): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kmz.TheCounsler-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kmz.TheCounsler-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.kmz.TheCounsler-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:201)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.(FlutterEngine.java:326)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.(FlutterEngine.java:206)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:252)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:162)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:430)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6739)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
E/FlutterLoader( 4087):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: i am trying by adding libflutter.so library manually but its not workint. Path is \android\app\src\main\jniLibs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am using agora rtc engin  4.2.0 in my app but it show the error that libflutter.so library has not been found and if i use older version something like 3.3.0 it work fine. what is the problem with the version having null safety

Answer (score 3):

In your app level build.gradle following line should be added

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this line to your android/app/build.gradle file

```
ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: If we add only "'armeabi-v7a'" in abiFilters then we won;t be able to publish that app on Play store.